# Reading Javascript local storage to populate autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I need to autocomplete a text field in a form. The data for the autocomplete will change from time to time, so I want to autopopulate the autocomplete. This will be running standalone with no net access, so I need a client side solution. Having the user select a file for the autopopulate is out of the question, so I wrote a .js file that creates a JSON object with the data to populate the autocomplete, as well as other data associated with the selection for the field.

I know the auto complete works if I give it a simple array:

```
$(function() {
    var cityList= ["Arlington Heights","Winnipeg","Miami Gardens","Louisville","Del Mar","Wilmington","Berkeley","Vancouver",]
//  var cityList= "Arlington Heights,Winnipeg,Miami Gardens,Louisville,Del Mar,Wilmington,Berkeley,Vancouver,"
    $( "#autocomp" ).autocomplete({ source: cityList });
});
```

However, when I read in the data from the .js file, things get really weird. This is the code I am using:

```
$(function() {
    citiesData ();
    var city = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem( ['cityData']));
    var cityList = '[';
    for(var row in city) {
        cityList = cityList += '"' + city[row].city +'",';
    };
    cityList += ']';
//  document.write('<br />' + cityList);
    $( "#autocomp" ).autocomplete({ source: cityList });
//  document.write('<br />; checkpoint 1');
})
```

By uncommenting the document.write above the autocomplete line, I can see that the variable cityList is exactly the same as the array entered in the first example. By uncommenting both document.write lines, I can see that they each get written, so the code is not hanging on the autocomplete. However, if I uncomment either or both of the document.write lines, the form never appears on the screen. I believe I mentioned that it got weird.

My real problem is not with that weirdness. My real problem is that the autocomplete never populates, although my solution is very similar to the one at tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_autocomplete.htm. I would really appreciate any insights into what my problem is with this.

I would also be interested if anyone can explain the weirdness about the document.write lines.

I have posted both versions. The first is at http://mccalip.com/problem/index.html.
The problem version is at http://mccalip.com/problem/problem.html.

Comment: How you are defining the array in the second time is the weird thing here..

Comment: Where is the `citiesData` method..? is it even a method..? Could you please tell us where did you find syntax like `localStorage.getItem( ['cityData'])`, and what you expects it to do..?

Comment: and by the way, `var cityList = '[]'` is a string, not an array. you might be looking for `Array.push()`

Comment: var city = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem( ['cityData']));
comes from http://htmldog.com/guides/javascript/advanced/localstorage/ and works very well.

citiesData is in <script src="tables/cityData.js"></script> that you can find in the example at http://mccalip.com/problem/problem.html.

Comment: So, pblsam, what is weird about it and how would you do it?

Comment: pblsam may be right. It looks you're concatenating a string instead of making a JSON obejct, and then write it to your local file. The 2nd autocomplete is parsing a JSON string, which is not the same thing as a JSON object. Concatenation is not bad per se, if you stick to it, then append at the beginning of your local file :  "var cityList = {"+your_entire_string+"}".

Comment: TJ, thank you for your suggestion. I went back to the working version (i.e., the first set of code posted above) and rewrote it to try cityList both with '[ ]' and without (the commented out line). It has to have the '[ ]' and double quotes around each item, so Array.push() would not work.

The variable, cityList, contains the exact same thing in both sets of code. I went into Show Page Source in Safari and looked at the Resource Content. This is an asynchronous issue; cityList does not get populated before autocomplete is loaded.

Given this new information, does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: @Bonatoc, yes, I parse and concatenate, because it gives me what I need. See my immediate previous comment. The parsing and concatenation works; open the second link in the original post and then look at the source code. This is an asynchronous processing issue. Given that information, do either of you have any suggestions?

Comment: @pblsam, please see comments above.

Comment: The most current versions are posted in my examples online:
The working version is at is at http://mccalip.com/problem/index.html. The problem version is at http://mccalip.com/problem/problem.html.

Comment: Turns out that @TJ was correct about using push instead of concatenating.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that works:

```
$(function() {
    readCity();
        var cityList = new Array;
    for (var c in arrayCity) {
        cityList.push(arrayCity[c][0]);
    };
    $( "#autocomp" ).autocomplete({ source: cityList });
});
```

readCity() is a function that creates the 2D array, arrayCity. Each row in the array has the city name followed by other data.

I just need the city names in the array for the autocomplete function, so I loop through arrayCity and push the names into the 1D array, cityList.